# Looping through 2d array

Tags: java

I am having difficulty with this code. I am trying to return a 2d which is the reverse of the input array. 
I am not sure how to code this correctly. Perhaps someone may have a few suggestions

```
public class arrays {
    int[][] transpose(int[][] a) {
        int[][] good = new int[a.length][a.length]; /* assign dimension, I want it to be the same as input */

        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < a[k].length; k++) { // //nested loop to go through the rows and columns
                good[i][k] = a[k][i]; // /// switch elements
            }
        }
        return good;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to think carefully which variable indicates a row, and which one a column. And in which array (`a` or `good`).

As I switched these around in your code, this improved version does work:

```
public class Arrays {
    static int[][] transpose(int[][] a) {
        // Only works if a is rectangular (every row in a has the same number of columns)
        int[][] good = new int[a[0].length][a.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            // Use a[i].length, not a[k].length because k will be bigger than a.length at some point.
            for (int k = 0; k < a[i].length; k++) {
                // i = row in 'a', column in 'good'
                // k = column in 'a', row in 'good'
                good[k][i] = a[i][k];
            }
        }
        return good;
    }
}
```

The problems were:

1. `int[][] good = new int[a.length][a.length];` Here you are creating a square matrix in `good` even though the original can be any rectangle shape (different number of rows and columns). You need to switch the number of rows and columns, so `new int[a[0].length][a.length]` is a good fix. (Assuming that all rows have an equal number of columns, which is required in a matrix)
2. `for (int k = 0; k < a[k].length; k++)` Here `k` is going to increase until it is larger than `a.length`, and you will get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` You want to loop over all columns in row `i`, so the upper bound is `a[i].length`, not `a[k]`.
3. `good[i][k] = a[k][i]` Remember that `i` was the row in **`a`**, not in `good`. In `good`, it is the column. So you need to swap your i's and k's on both sides of the assignment.